# Adding WebAPI to an existing MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC5 application, which works normally. It has models, controllers, views, and all the other functionality. It is already a stand-alone app. I now want to create an API for this application. I don't know whether I should create a new WebAPI project in the same solution, or use my existing MVC project, to also include the API functionality there. Which is the appropriate way? Please note that later I want to use that API for creating a mobile application using Xamarin.

Comment: Are you planning to host the API in the same location as your MVC app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the same project, in many ways it makes the most sense as it will be easier when hosting the application if they live within the same web project.

I tend to keep my API controllers in a subfolder called "Api" which is neatly located within the Controllers folder of the web solution.

"Controllers > Api".

When i'm not sure with these kinds of things I tend to go with the simplest option, later on down the line if you find a good reason to locate the controllers in their own project for some reason this is easily achieved.

You mentioned that you will be using the API to develop an application using XAMARIN later on and this should not mean moving the API... mobile apps will not need any kind of reference to the API at all, they will simply be calling your application using standard HTTP requests. It will make no difference and again as you are going to need a host for your website, you might as well use the same host for your API too.

Answer (score -1):

If you want use `WebAPI` not only for `WebSite` - SO sure, you have add new `WebAPI` project in solution
(+ it's better in `OOP`) - it be easy to change.

Comment: I disagree, It has nothing to do with OOP. API controllers are unlikely to be used by other projects as their primary purpose will be to serve data over HTTP. The OP will gain more from keeping API controllers in his web project.

Comment: I mean - that from OOP Side - be right write WebAPI like NEW PROJECT because - Website - it's website, and WebAPI its WebAPI - its don't need be in 1 project. And If tomorrow you will need change something in WebAPi  you need Change/Build only WebAPI and not ALL your website + webapi

+ You write that you want use WebAPI for Xamarin - so be very good that WebAPI will end point for get data to ALL your platforms (It's one of roles OOP too)

Comment: Completely disagree with that but each to their own.